# What setting in XP stops executables being run unless you're an administrator?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, restrictions

If I go to a workstation in a certain large organisation and try to run an executable from a USB drive it doesn't let me.

What setting is this in Group Policy or wherever else that does this?

Comment: Your question is lacking in details like what is the OS running for example.

Comment: @Dragos: see tags

Answer (score 6):

I'd guess it's Software Restriction Policies.

Comment: More detail is required for me to accept this answer.  How do you modify Software Restriction Policies?

Answer (score 5):

For security reasons there may be a restriction on running executables from removable media. I suggest you talk to the system admins in that organisation to learn what you may or may not do.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the tool that does this, not why.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities.  Including, but not limited too the following.

- The application needs to write to the registry at places not permitted by the ACLs
- It need to write to the file-system at places not permitted by the ACLs
- It needs to load a kernel driver
- The system has policies in place to block certain executables (or usually block everything and permit good things).

Comment: And lets not forget antivirus software that can emulate this behaviour.